# DAX Calculation SUMX

Tags: dax

I have this line of DAX Calculation:

```
Sumx(‘Fact Exchange Rate’, ‘Fact Exchange Rate’[Exchange Rate] * ‘Fact ClientValuation Diff’[Valuation Difference In Val Ccy])
```

I'm not familiar with DAX but I understand the first argument in the Sumx is a table. Here the table is 'Fact Exchange Rate'. Then we multiply each value in the column Exchange Rate of this table with a value in a different table i.e. Fact ClientValuation Diff and sum it all up to get one single value, right?

So what I am confused about is why have we only specified just one of the tables in the first argument when the whole expression is using two different tables?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your above DAX Function, which is SUMX which will Return the sum of an expression evaluated for each row in a table. First expression is a table name(The table containing the rows for which the expression will be evaluated) and second is expression(The expression to be evaluated for each row of the table).

If **Exchange Rate** and **Valuation Difference In Val Ccy** are present in the same table, it should work absolutely fine, if not they should be related to each other(**Fact Exchange Rate & Fact ClientValuation Diff**) in one or the other way.

For more info please https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/sumx-function-dax

Comment: I have explicitly written in my initial post that they are coming from two different tables. Exchange Rate and Valuation Difference in Val Ccy are not in the same table.

Comment: Please try to understand the answer properly : if columns are coming from two different tables then they should be related to each other(Fact Exchange Rate & Fact ClientValuation Diff) in one or the other way.

Comment: Elaborate? What do you specifically mean if columns are related to each other?